# (c++) what happens to objects on the heap that don't have any pointers to them?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, heap-memory

do they become memory leaks or does c++ realize they have no pointers aiming at them and free up that memory? If they must be deleted i just use the delete command right?

Comment: Nothing; they sit there, occupying space, never to be reused.  It's called a memory leak, and is bad news.

Comment: That's a memory leak by definition.

Comment: And before you get the wrong idea that C++ is this difficult language where you need to constantly be taking care to release your memory, you don't.  That's why we have [container classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), which allow `delete` to be completely avoided in most user code. `new` can also be almost completely avoided, with the exception of creating a `unique_ptr` (a remedy for this is in process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does c++ realize they have no pointers aiming at them and free up that memory?

C++ does not "realize" any such thing. There is no built-in garbage collector.

If you allocate memory with `new` and don't free it with a corresponding call to `delete`, you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Cody is correct, C++ does not have a garbage collector so you would have a memory leak when the pointer to the object is lost.

C++ does have something in the std library to address this. The `std::shared_ptr` will automatically delete the object if the object no longer has any `std::shared_ptr` pointed to it.